# ES6 catching submit event

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I don't get why when clicking on a button inside `#mydiv` the eventlistener is not catching the event and outputting "submitted". The Buttons are just submitting the form.

```
import { $, $$, on, data } from 'uikit-util';

export default function () {

    const searchform = document.getElementById('myform');

    searchform.addEventListener('submit', e => {

        e.preventDefault();

        console.log("submitted");
    });

    on($$('#mydiv button[type="button"]'), 'click', function (e) {
        document.getElementById('myform').submit();
    });

}
```

Comment: Because [`submit` just submits the form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit), without triggering any events or doing validation. You really should change the type of those buttons to `submit` and not install custom click handlers.

Comment: I did it before with jQuery `$("#myform").submit()`. That worked, why?

Comment: `import { $, $$ }` makes my eyes hurt.

Comment: import { $, $$ } is Uikit utils: https://github.com/uikit/uikit/tree/develop/src/js/util

Comment: @Mike Because in [jQuery it means `.trigger('submit')`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Comment: @Bergi ok, i see. Thanks.